# PHP SQL ROW Proper Format

Tags: php, sql

What is the proper way to print a list of rows?

```
<?php
    $list = '';
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

        $name = $row["name"]; // row in set var

        $list.= '<li>'.$name.'</li>'; // set variable in list var
    }
?>

<html>
    <ul><?php print $list ?></ul>
</html>
```

Or this.

```
<?php
    $list = '';
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

        $list.= '<li>'.$row["name"].'</li>'; // row in list var

    }
?>

<html>
    <ul><?php print $list ?></ul>
</html>
```

I know this seems like a silly question, but to me it is not.  I have used both methods, and I am curious..

- Is there a prefered method?
- Is one way faster (even by a fraction of a millasecond)
- Which one is more formal

PS: I usually use PDO so please dont bag on the mysql, i just typed this up for examples sake.

Thank you for your feedback in advance.

Comment: Ideally your business logic and presentation layers will be spearate

Comment: You can test it to see what is faster with microtime and memory_get_usage functions and stuff like that, but what John Conde pointed, for bigger projects it's easier to have business logic separated from you template files. That way, the code is more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Great points Whirlwind.  This is enough of an answer for me for this question to be closed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, instead of storing and printing, you can can directly print in your HTML.

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $list = '';
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

        echo '<li>'.$row["name"].'</li>'; // row in list var

    }
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Right, I am aware of this.  My question isn't in regards to placement of the query itself, it was proper placement of the `$row` within the while loop.  Thanks for your answer anyhow.

Comment: If I would have to chose, I would prefer second option. The first one only adds up an extra step, which is useless. So keep it simple. Keeping that aside, it also depends to whom and where you will be presenting or using this piece of code... :)

Comment: That was my thoughts.  I figured there is no need to put the `$row` into a separate variable unless it will be used elsewhere on the page.

Comment: Yup, no use of extra added lines...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the faster method is the one who avoids using redundant variables and unnecessary methods. Notice that you are concatenating strings in a `while` so you are making one concat for each row of the table.

The best method in my opinion would be something like this.

PHP Part:

```
    $results = array();//This is only to be sure that the array is empty
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
         $results[] = $row['name'];
    }
?>
```

HTML Part:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($results as $result){ ?>
         <li><?php echo $result; ?></li>
    <? } ?>
</ul>
```

By doing this you avoid those concats and you also keep the HTML away from the PHP code. Maybe it's not the fastest option but I think it's fast enough, formal and clean.

Also, maintaining HTML code inside PHP code it's a pain in the ass so I truly recommend you to avoid that even out of this example.